# Prototype Event

Tags: prototype, события, javascript

Добрый деньвечер. Используя prototype.js столкнулся с проблемой:
На все элементы `<a class='someclass'>` вешаю event

```
var x = $$('.someclass');
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
   Event.observe(x[i], 'click', this.popup.bindAsEventListener(this));
}
```

Но, по нажатию он переходит по ссылке, указанной в свойстве href. Но он не должен. Использовать другие свойства для ссылки, находящейся в свойстве href нельзя. Решил проблему прописав в элементы свойство `onCLick="return false;"`. Хочу более лаконичное решение. Я так понял необходимо использовать `Event.stop();`? Но как? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Останавливается так, например:

```
 for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
       Event.observe(x[i], 'click', function(e){
             // some code there ...
             Event.stop(e);
       });
 }
```

Я так понимаю this.popup.bindAsEventListener(this) возвращает функию, если да, то достаточно переписать код так:

```
   var eventHandler = this.popup.bindAsEventListener(this);
   for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
       Event.observe(x[i], 'click', function(e){
           eventHandler();
           Event.stop(e);
       });
   }
```

Вообще вопрос элементарный, в следующий раз смотрите сначала здесь - [Prototype JS API](http://api.prototypejs.org/), да и гугл никто не отменял

Comment: Спасибо, видимо плохо искал :)

Comment: Судя по всему =)